# jquery -- prevent mouseover behavior when item becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a button, "Add to Cart" which sends an ajax request when clicked. After the request returns successfully, the the button is replaced by "In Your Cart". "In Your Cart" has a mouseover state: "Remove From Cart".

The design requirement is that "Remove From Cart" only appear when the user physically moves the mouse over "In Your Cart". If they simply click "Add to Cart" and don't move the mouse, the button should say "In Your Cart" after the ajax call completes, even if the mouse is still over the element.

A simple mouseover event listener doesn't work, because it triggers when the element becomes visible. I'm considering counting mouseovers and mouseouts of a wrapper element, in order to determine if the mouseover event is "real", or just the result of the element becoming visible, but that's really ugly. Any other ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (edit as appropriate for your AJAX call):

HTML:

```
<div class="cart">
    <button class="add-cart">Add to Cart</button>
    <button class="in-cart" style="display:none;">In Your Cart</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var $addCart = $('.add-cart');
var $inCart = $('.in-cart');

$addCart.click( function(e){
    $addCart.hide();
    $inCart.show().addClass( 'initial' );
});

$inCart.mouseover( function(){
    if( ! $inCart.is( '.initial' ) ){
        $inCart.text( 'Remove from Cart' );
    }
});

$inCart.mouseout( function(){
    $inCart.text( 'In Your Cart' ).removeClass( 'initial' );
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U94aV/1/)

**UPDATE**

Based on OP's comment below, I've update the HTML and Javascript as follows:

```
<span class='cart'>
    <button class="add-cart">Add to Cart</button>
    <button class="in-cart" style="display:none;">In Your Cart</button>
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var $cart = $('.cart');
var $addCart = $('.add-cart');
var $inCart = $('.in-cart');

$addCart.click( function(e){
    $addCart.attr('disabled','disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $addCart.hide();
        $inCart.show();
    }, 1000);
});

$cart.mouseenter( function(){
    if( $inCart.is(':visible') ){
        $inCart.text( 'Remove from Cart' );
    }
});

$cart.mouseleave( function(){
    if( $inCart.is(':visible') ){
        $inCart.text( 'In Your Cart' );
    }
});
```

The differences here are:

1. The `add-cart` button is disabled while AJAX is simulated and then hidden.
2. `mouseover` and `mouseout` have been replaced with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.
3. These events are now tied to the `span` wrapper so that the user mouse behavior can be tracked better since the `span` never hides itself.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfgBm/5/)

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle, but it doesn't work if the user moves the mouse out before the request returns. I added a timer to your jsfiddle to simulate. http://jsfiddle.net/GfgBm/

Comment: @morgancodes See my update above. Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I do believe it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent an event from firing by using jQuery's event.preventDefault();

I would write it this way:

```
$('#elementid').mouseover(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will stop it from doing what it is supposed to do until you manually fire it later, or add code after the event.preventDefault(); to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery, mouseenter and mouseleave only fire when you enter or leave... so use a static sized wrapper for your image

onsuccess of the ajax, fade the image to what you want

mouseenter, check a flag you set when add to cart was clicked, if its set, you know the user clicked order, moved the mouse, then moved back in..